# How to create column based on another column on Policy Level SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have table like this:

```
declare @ClaimType table (PolicyNumber varchar(50), QuoteID int,  CoverageType varchar(50))

insert into @ClaimType values   ('00001',1, 'CSO'),
                                ('00001',2, 'CPL'),
                                ('00001',3, 'EO'),
                                ('00002',1, 'CPL'),
                                ('00002',2, 'CGL')

select QuoteID,
        PolicyNumber,      
        CoverageType
from @ClaimType
go
```

[image]

I need to create column 'AnnualStatementLine' and generate value in it based on `CoverageType`

On a policy level I need to check whether CoverageType has 'CGL' value or not. If not then write '17.1' otherwise '19.1'

So there are no  `CoverageType 'CGL'` for  `PolicyNumber 00001`  so `AnnualStatementLine` should be 17.1

For policy 00002 one of the values has 'CGL', so need to be '19.1'

Is it possible to achieve that in single select statement?

The result should look like this:

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS` :

```
SELECT ct.*,
       (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                          FROM @ClaimType ct1 
                          WHERE ct1.PolicyNumber = ct.PolicyNumber AND ct1.CoverageType = 'CGL'
                         ) 
             THEN '19.1' 
             ELSE '17.1'
        END) AS AnnualStatementLine
FROM @ClaimType ct;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query using `IN` clause.

```
declare @ClaimType table (PolicyNumber varchar(50), QuoteID int,  CoverageType varchar(50))

insert into @ClaimType values   ('00001',1, 'CSO'),
                                ('00001',2, 'CPL'),
                                ('00001',3, 'EO'),
                                ('00002',1, 'CPL'),
                                ('00002',2, 'CGL')

select QuoteID,
        PolicyNumber,      
        CoverageType,
        case when PolicyNumber IN (Select PolicyNumber from @ClaimType where CoverageType = 'CGL') then 19.1
        else 17.1 end as AnnualStatementLine
from @ClaimType
```

[**Demo Link**](https://rextester.com/WQDB21721)